# Uploaded Binary Doesn't Appear On iTunes Connect in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, app-store, app-store-connect

I have uploaded my new build through `Xcode` for submit app on app store but it doesn't appear on iTunes Connect.

Then i tried with application loader, then it shows:

> ERROR ITMS-4238: "Redundant Binary Upload. There already exists a binary upload with build version '1.6.2' for train '1.6'" at SoftwareAssets/PreReleaseSoftwareAsset.

Then I check on iTunes Connect, the build is not even seen in activity nor in build Section. And in my App Information Section of iTunes Connect, it shows warning of

> You must release a new app version before your updates can be made available on the App Store.

Then I change version number and upload app through application loader and Build was uploaded successfully. Still that build is not appear on iTunes connect and still that warning is appear on App Information page that:

> You must release a new app version before your updates can be made available on the App Store.

Now what should I do to solve this problem and upload new version of app on app store?

Comment: This happened to me before. Check your email, the one you are using in itunesconnect. See if there are any emails that apple sent you. In my case I have something in my code that needs to be changed. And don't forget to change your app version when you upload it again.

Comment: Did you check activity tab of your app? Maybe your binary is still being processed?

Comment: Yes, I have checked activity tab.but there are no build appear.

Comment: I have the same issue and my build doesn't appear in activity tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps to build upload. These steps can be resolved your problem

1. Launch Application Loader.
2. In the top menu bar, click Application Loader > Preferences.
3. Choose Advanced.
4. Under Transfer Protocol, deselect Aspera.
5. Close the Preferences window and proceed with the delivery.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but nothing happenes.still there is nothing in activity tab as well as in build section.

Comment: Please contact apple team

Comment: so there is no other option that i should try?

Comment: 1(877)388-0879 ext. 1100844
Monday through Friday, 10:30a.m. to 7:30p.m. central time.

Comment: What does Aspera do and why we should deselect it?